# How to compile for armv6 with Monotouch and XCode 4.5+

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, armv6

It is possible to compile for armv6 in newer versions of XCode (4.5+) by installing a prior SDK into XCode.  See http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081

This is useful when wanting to develop different applications with different platform targets and feature sets.

How can you compile a Monotouch application to armv6 using a newer version of XCode (but older SDK)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch) does not really depend on an specific Xcode, but some things will adjust themselves with the installed version.

You do not need to hack your currently installed Xcode (too many things can go wrong) but you can install several versions of Xcode side-by-side, e.g. I got 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 and 4.5 on my same Lion laptop. Just rename the one installed at the default location before installing a new one.

When you select an old Xcode (from Xamarin Studio, or older MonoDevelop releases, preferences) it should adjust to the *right* features. IOW once 4.4 is installed (and set as default) then ARMv6 should be available.